# Establish \fontseries for entire document

Tags: fonts

I want to use the `light` weight of the `Open Sans` package as my default font for a paper. It works perfectly fine using the following:

```
\begin{document}
    {\fontseries{l}\selectfont
        \input{...}
}
\end{document}
```

(of course there's more, but you get what I mean)

Although this works fine, I'm not really satisfied as this looks quite messy. I tried using `renewcommand` but could not figure out how to make `\fontseries{l} \selectfont` my default sans font.

Also, I'd like to do something similar for bold writing: I'd like to use `\fontseries{sb}` there. As I said before, this code (and thus the font weights) work like a charm when I use the mentioned commands within my document.

Comment: semantically same question as in "How can one change an entire document to use bold font?" The first one should be generalized, rephrased and both should be merged.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The default font can be set by changing `\encodingdefault`, `\familydefault`, `\seriesdefault`, and `\shapedefault`. In your example, I would go for

```
\renewcommand{\seriesdefault}{l}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
```

to set the light sans font as the main font.

Comment: works great! Just in case anybody is looking for this: `\renewcommand{\bfseries}{\fontseries{sb}\selectfont}` makes the bold font semi-bold for me.